# Parametros da função exec

Tags: c

Estava fazendo um exercício de um livro e nele tem a seguinte ordem:

Olhando os parâmetros da função **exec**:
[Função **exec**](http://www.dca.ufrn.br/~adelardo/cursos/DCA409/node39.html)
Não fala sobre nenhum parâmetro que pode ser passado para informar quantas vezes aquele **Exec** deve executar.
Alguém sabe se existe algum tipo de exec que faz isso?

Comment: O texto tá meio esquisito mas acho que ele deve estar falando de montar um *array* com o número de processos. É só um chute. Outra possibilidade é que você deve fazer uma função que recebe este parâmetro e trate dele para executar a `exec()`.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez o pedido seja uma coisa tipo chamada recursiva.

```
// programa 'pai'
    execl("filho.exe", "filho.exe", "4", 0);
```

e o programa 'filho' apanha o valor, diminui 1 e chama-se a ele proprio ate ser zero.

```
// programa 'filho' (falta validacao de erros)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("filho #%d\n", n);
    if (n > 1) {
        char tmp[10];
        sprintf(tmp, "%d", n - 1);
        execl("filho.exe", "filho.exe", tmp, 0); // chamada "recursiva"
    }
    return 0;
}
```